# Page number not showing in R markdown beamer while using a latex template

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using a latex template to create a beamer presentation in R markdown. Everything works fine, except that the page number is not showing in the foot line. I went through the latex template code and still cannot figure out what's wrong there. Any contributions are welcome.

You should be able to clone from my [github](https://github.com/dayabin/AnExampleTAMUBeamer.git). In the template code, I suspect the problem might be around the `\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}` code chunk. We might directly navigate to that code chunk and figure out the glitch.

As requested by one of contributors in the comment section, I uploaded the generated `.tex` file below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,ignorenonframetext,,aspectratio=149]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=normal text.fg}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}

% Comment these out if you don't want a slide with just the
% part/section/subsection/subsubsection title:
\AtBeginPart{
  \let\insertpartnumber\relax
  \let\partname\relax
  \frame{\partpage}
}
\AtBeginSection{
  \let\insertsectionnumber\relax
  \let\sectionname\relax
  \frame{\sectionpage}
}
\AtBeginSubsection{
  \let\insertsubsectionnumber\relax
  \let\subsectionname\relax
  \frame{\subsectionpage}
}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{Weekly GAMS Meeting}
\author{Yabin Da}
\date{2020-10-15}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% Here's everything I added.
%%--------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{amsmath}


% Get rid of navigation symbols.
%-------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Optional institute tags and titlegraphic.
% Do feel free to change the titlegraphic if you don't want it as a Markdown field.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\institute{Department of Agricultural Economics}


% <-- Somehow, the if sentence below did not work for me. I, therefore, placed the absolute path below and it worked. 
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth]{C:/work/Study/Y 2020/Ozone in China/report/tamu/tamu.png}} 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%

% Some additional title page adjustments.
%----------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[empty]
%\date{}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

% Some optional colors. Change or add as you see fit.
%---------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{tamumaroon}{HTML}{500000}
\definecolor{tamuwhite}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{uiucblue}{HTML}{003C7D}
\definecolor{uiucorange}{HTML}{F47F24}


% Some optional color adjustments to Beamer. Change as you see fit.
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tamuwhite, bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=tamuwhite, bg=tamumaroon}


\let\Tiny=\tiny


% Sections and subsections should not get their own damn slide.
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\AtBeginPart{}
\AtBeginSection{}
\AtBeginSubsection{}
\AtBeginSubsubsection{}

% Suppress some of Markdown's weird default vertical spacing.
%------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}


% Allow for those simple two-tone footlines I like. 
% Edit the colors as you see fit.
%--------------------------------------------------
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}{%
    \ifnum\insertpagenumber=1
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.8ex,dp=1ex,center]{}%
      % empty environment to raise height
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
    \else%
        \Tiny{%
            \hfill%
        \vspace*{1pt}%
            \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \hspace*{0.1cm}%
            \newline%
            \color{tamumaroon}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4mm}}\newline%
            \color{tamumaroon}{\rule{\paperwidth}{.4mm}}%
        }%
    \fi%
}

% Various cosmetic things, though I must confess I forget what exactly these do and why I included them.
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{parent=item,use=item,fg=tamumaroon,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{parent=item}

% Adjust some item elements. More cosmetic things.
%-------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{tamumaroon}$\bullet$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{tamumaroon}\scriptsize{$\bullet$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body end}{\vspace{.6\baselineskip}} % So I'm less inclined to use \medskip and \bigskip in Markdown.

% Automatically center images
% ---------------------------
% Note: this is for ![](image.png) images
% Use "fig.align = "center" for R chunks

% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% 
% \AtBeginDocument{%
%   \letcs\oig{@orig\string\includegraphics}%
%   \renewcommand<>\includegraphics[2][]{%
%     \only#3{%
%       {\centering\oig[{#1}]{#2}\par}%
%     }%
%   }%
% }

% I think I've moved to xelatex now. Here's some stuff for that.
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% I could customize/generalize this more but the truth is it works for my circumstances.

\ifxetex
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontspec{serif}}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\fontspec{serif}}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
 \else
 \fi

% Okay, and begin the actual document...

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\hypertarget{meeting-on-october-15}{%
\section{Meeting on October 15}\label{meeting-on-october-15}}

\begin{frame}{Potential problems}
\protect\hypertarget{potential-problems}{}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  The current optimization model is not easy to maximum over a set of
  objectives. That is because we only have one single objective
  function.
\item
  Even though we include multiple envrionmental benefits into the
  objective function, since the units are different, we cannot simply
  sum over those benefits and then maximize the benefit.
\item
  I guess the unit is pounds per acre for environmental losses and
  dollars per acre for cost. The scale factor for unit is 1000.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\section[]{}
\frame{\small \frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a [**minimal**, and complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Dumping the whole template and without an example is not the best practice.

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: probably unrelated to the problem, but you will get into trouble with incorrectly calculated footheight due to your if-condition in the footline

Comment: That said, why do you load every package but the kitchen sink? Most of them are loaded automatically by beamer and some will cause more problems than they solve

Comment: And even worse, why do you load the same packages multiple times?????????

Comment: The syntax `\Tiny{...}` is wrong, it is a switch and does not take an argument. Without inserting a paragraph after text passages in another size your linespread will be messed up

Comment: Don't ever uncomment  the `% Automatically center images` part, that makes zero sense in a document class that centres images by default

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the comments. You just pointed a very good question: why I loaded some packages multiple times? The problem is even though some of the packages are included in the template, I HAVE TO include in the YAML as well, otherwise I got problems when rendering to pdf. For instance, I have to include the `booktabs` package in the YAML to get rid of problems when using `kable`.

Comment: I just edited the post and provided my github. You are welcome to clone to your local machine and help me out.

Comment: @YabinDa Can you add `keep_tex: true` to your rmarkdown file and show the resulting tex file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz tex file uploaded. You are welcome to point out any problems in the latex template cuz I am gonna save it as my primary beamer template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame numbers become visible if you set them in any other colour than white:

```
\documentclass[10pt,ignorenonframetext,,aspectratio=149]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{: }
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=normal text.fg}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}

% Comment these out if you don't want a slide with just the
% part/section/subsection/subsubsection title:
\AtBeginPart{
  \let\insertpartnumber\relax
  \let\partname\relax
  \frame{\partpage}
}
\AtBeginSection{
  \let\insertsectionnumber\relax
  \let\sectionname\relax
  \frame{\sectionpage}
}
\AtBeginSubsection{
  \let\insertsubsectionnumber\relax
  \let\subsectionname\relax
  \frame{\subsectionpage}
}

\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{Weekly GAMS Meeting}
\author{Yabin Da}
\date{2020-10-15}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% Here's everything I added.
%%--------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{amsmath}


% Get rid of navigation symbols.
%-------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Optional institute tags and titlegraphic.
% Do feel free to change the titlegraphic if you don't want it as a Markdown field.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\institute{Department of Agricultural Economics}


% <-- Somehow, the if sentence below did not work for me. I, therefore, placed the absolute path below and it worked. 
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth]{example-image}} 
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%

% Some additional title page adjustments.
%----------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[empty]
%\date{}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

% Some optional colors. Change or add as you see fit.
%---------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{tamumaroon}{HTML}{500000}
\definecolor{tamuwhite}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\definecolor{uiucblue}{HTML}{003C7D}
\definecolor{uiucorange}{HTML}{F47F24}


% Some optional color adjustments to Beamer. Change as you see fit.
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=tamuwhite,bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tamuwhite, bg=tamumaroon}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=tamuwhite, bg=tamumaroon}


\let\Tiny=\tiny


% Sections and subsections should not get their own damn slide.
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\AtBeginPart{}
\AtBeginSection{}
\AtBeginSubsection{}
\AtBeginSubsubsection{}

% Suppress some of Markdown's weird default vertical spacing.
%------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}


% Allow for those simple two-tone footlines I like. 
% Edit the colors as you see fit.
%--------------------------------------------------
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my footline}{%
    \ifnum\insertpagenumber=1
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=.8ex,dp=1ex,center]{}%
      % empty environment to raise height
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }%
    \vskip0pt%
    \else%
        \color{tamumaroon}%
        \Tiny{%
            \hfill%
        \vspace*{1pt}%
            \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \hspace*{0.1cm}%
            \newline%
            \color{tamumaroon}{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4mm}}\newline%
            \color{tamumaroon}{\rule{\paperwidth}{.4mm}}%
        }%
    \fi%
}

% Various cosmetic things, though I must confess I forget what exactly these do and why I included them.
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{parent=item,use=item,fg=tamumaroon,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{parent=item}

% Adjust some item elements. More cosmetic things.
%-------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{tamumaroon}$\bullet$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\color{tamumaroon}\scriptsize{$\bullet$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body end}{\vspace{.6\baselineskip}} % So I'm less inclined to use \medskip and \bigskip in Markdown.

% Automatically center images
% ---------------------------
% Note: this is for ![](image.png) images
% Use "fig.align = "center" for R chunks

% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% 
% \AtBeginDocument{%
%   \letcs\oig{@orig\string\includegraphics}%
%   \renewcommand<>\includegraphics[2][]{%
%     \only#3{%
%       {\centering\oig[{#1}]{#2}\par}%
%     }%
%   }%
% }

% I think I've moved to xelatex now. Here's some stuff for that.
% --------------------------------------------------------------
% I could customize/generalize this more but the truth is it works for my circumstances.

\ifxetex
\setbeamerfont{title}{family=\fontspec{serif}}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\fontspec{serif}}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
 \else
 \fi

% Okay, and begin the actual document...

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\hypertarget{meeting-on-october-15}{%
\section{Meeting on October 15}\label{meeting-on-october-15}}

\begin{frame}{Potential problems}
\protect\hypertarget{potential-problems}{}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  The current optimization model is not easy to maximum over a set of
  objectives. That is because we only have one single objective
  function.
\item
  Even though we include multiple envrionmental benefits into the
  objective function, since the units are different, we cannot simply
  sum over those benefits and then maximize the benefit.
\item
  I guess the unit is pounds per acre for environmental losses and
  dollars per acre for cost. The scale factor for unit is 1000.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\section[]{}
\frame{\small \frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Some unrelated remarks:

- `\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}` is unnecessary, beamer loads this
- `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`, `\usepackage{microtype}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` unnecessary if your tex distribution is reasonable new. That's default now
- you don't need `\usepackage{caption}` with beamer, beamer has its own mechanism to deal with captions
- `xcolor`, `hyperref` and `graphicx` is not necessary, beamer loads it
- several package are loaded multiple times
- first setting `\AtBeginPart` etc and clearing it later makes not much sense
- `\frame{}` only works for lecagy reasons, use `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` instead

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution. One last question what did you mean by "Don't ever uncomment the % Automatically center images part". I cannot create side by side images with `Knitr::include_graphics` if I did not comment it off. The side by side will always be vertically stacked.

Comment: @YabinDa No idea what `Knitr::include_graphics` does, but beamer automatically centres the contents of `figure` environments. It makes no sense to me to add `\centering` to includegraphics